# CSS to show responsive Nag Bar?

Tags: android, html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

We're using a WordPress theme called "Covert PinPress" which is basically a knock-off of Pinterest.

Here's an example page:

**http://shoeporn.com/iron-fist-death-dance/**

The **#header_banner** yellow banner at the top can be viewed on laptops/desktops, but not mobile devices.

It's clear why, because in the theme's style.css, it has:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px) {
#header_banner { display:  none; }
}
```

And

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
#header_banner, #header #search {display:  none;}   
}
```

If I was to remove those entries, the banner would appear on my Android, but it looks terrible.  It's way too wide, and it overlaps other objects on the page.

Screeny:

[image: Android screenshot]

Any ideas how I can modify the CSS so it looks good on all devices?  Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px) {
```

## header_banner {  width: 100%; font-size: the size you need/want !important; .nag-bar-widget { width: 90%;

} }
}

explication: you must change the style-attributes who gives the element a fixed size. The !important you need, because the font-size of the span element is defined in the html-document.

if anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately it doesn't look very good. See my Android screeny:  http://d.pr/i/NgMF

Answer (score 0):

Use % rather than px, you need to make the menu responsive rather that set to a set size as when it is viewed on a smaller devise it will not adjust accordingly. The answer above is perfect and will work.
When working with cross devise sites always make the site responsive as that way it should work cross platform.
I hope this helps.

```
      .nag-bar-widget {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000%;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
        #header_banner {
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
background: url(images/banner.png) no-repeat;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -340px;
text-align: left;
width: 50%;
height: 30%;
top: 50%;
padding: 5px 21px 10px;
z-index: 100;
}
```

Also the div where you have the image and text plese correct with.

```
    <div style="margin-top: auto;">
<a href="http://shoeporn.com/go/keen-akita-ankle-boot" target="_blank"><img src="http://shoeporn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Keen-Akita-Ankle-Boot.jpg" style="border:1px #BBBBBB solid; height:50px; vertical-align:middle; margin-right:10px;"></a>
<span style="font-size:2em;"><a href="http://shoeporn.com/go/keen-akita-ankle-boot" target="_blank" style="color:black;">Keen Akita Ankle Boot - now on sale for $44.99!</a></span>
</div>
```

**make these changes to**

```
   .tack_entry {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(34, 25, 25, .4);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(34, 25, 25, .4);
background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 80%;
padding: 15% 10% 10%;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

**also these changes**

```
 #header_banner {
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
background: url(images/banner.png) no-repeat;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -340px;
text-align: left;
width: 100%;
height: 85px;
top: 110px;
padding: 5px 21px 10px;
z-index: 100;
}
```

**and this**

```
    #logo {
left: 50%;
height: 16%;
top: 2px;
margin-left: -260px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
}
```

**Finally**

```
 #header {
width: 85%;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}
```

This should fix your problem

Comment: Unfortunately using the CSS above, the banner is floating on top of other page elements and is way too far to the left.  See http://d.pr/i/NgMF

Comment: Have updated with code that will fix this in my answer. hope this is clear for you.

Comment: how ever you will need to change you #header-nav

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "change you #header-nav", what do I change it to?  I tried everything you said above, on my Android I briefly see the yellow banner when the page loads, then it disappears off the left side of the screen and I can't see it again.  Changing the image/text div to "margin-top: auto;" just makes it squish up towards the grey line above, which looks worse.

Comment: you will need to go through most of the css and make it responsive as when one element changes it will affect the rest unless they are responsive to, try changing all px to %

Comment: see my update to the solution, will fix your problem once it works please vote up and accept the answer, thank you.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts, but unfortunately it just keeps looking worse and worse, the more changes I implement.  See latest Android screeny: http://d.pr/i/zfV9  The nag bar is WAY far left, you can't even scroll to see it, you just see it poking out if you scroll down the page.

Comment: hm its hard trying to convert a built theme maybe try http://wordpress.org/plugins/app-your-wordpress-uppsite/